# Error message: "MemCache requires PHP memcache extension to be loaded." after migration.

Tags: php, yii2, memcached

From phpinfo():
[phpinfo, memcache is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ill3B.png)

However, when I try to migrate, show this error:

```
Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'MemCache requires PHP memcache extension to be loaded.'

in /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/caching/MemCache.php:217

Stack trace:
#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/caching/MemCache.php(113): yii\caching\MemCache->getMemcache()
#1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php(107): yii\caching\MemCache->init()
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#3 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(372): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#4 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(151): yii\di\Container->build('yii\\caching\\Mem...', Array, Array)
#5 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(344): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\caching\\Mem...', Array, Array)
#6 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(133): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#7 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php(275): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('cache', false)
#8 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Migration.php(71): yii\db\Schema->refresh()
#9 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php(107): yii\db\Migration->init()
#10 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/MigrateController.php(113): yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#11 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(491): yii\console\controllers\MigrateController->createMigration('m170316_221710_...')
#12 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(129): yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->migrateUp('m170316_221710_...')
#13 [internal function]: yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->actionUp(0)
#14 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(151): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#16 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(91): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#17 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(455): yii\console\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#18 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(167): yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate', Array)
#19 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(143): yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate', Array)
#20 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#21 /Library/WebServer/Documents/r2d2/yii(27): yii\base\Application->run()
#22 {main}
```

Could someone help me find out why?

Thanks!

Comment: .... maybe try install the memcache extension?

Answer (score 0):

The error is from console application and phpinfo output is from webserver. So, you basically enabled memcache module for webserver but didn't for console. To give exact solution more information about your setup is needed: what do you​ use, php-fpm, modapache? Please provide full phpinfo output either from web and cli

**UPDATE**

Check which directories your console PHP scans for additional ini-files:

```
php -i | grep "Scan this dir for additional .ini files"
```

Then you need to put configuration file (for example `memcache.ini`) with module config into one of those. Content should be like:

```
extension=memcache.so
```

You can check the one webserver uses for reference.

Comment: I have tried `php -i` in console and it does not show memcache is enabled. Could you please tell me how to enable module for console?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: The strange thing is that migration is working fine on my other yii2 website on the same computer, but going wrong with `Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'MemCache requires PHP memcache extension to be loaded.'` this error. Is there any incorrect config I should notice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use memcached instead memcache, then you need to add this line to config/console.php:

```
'useMemcached' => true,
```

it should look like:

```
'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
        'useMemcached' => true,
        'servers' => [
            [
```

....